# Binary neural network skews towards one class despite balanced training data

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, neural-network, tflearn

When training my binary neural network I'm observing something curious. Despite the test and training data and labels being balanced and symmetric, the network's predictions are not.
After 100 epochs this is what I get:

```
1 prediction: 0.89635      0 prediction: 0.4742
```

I was expecting an even 0.5, 0.5 split.
Why does the network skew towards one side?

My network is trying to predict the winner in a basketball game given an input vector of the scores of all 10 players. The output is a sigmoid indicating whether team 1 is winning. The network should be symmetric, i.e if [team1_scores,team2_scores] = 1 then [team2_scores,team1_scores] = 0. To ensure this I flip the training data and labels so that the winning and the losing team are in both places in the input vector.

Here is my code:

```
from tflearn.layers.core import fully_connected, input_data
from tflearn.layers.estimator import regression
import tflearn
import numpy as np

#flip data so that [team1_scores, team2_scores] becomes [team2_scores, team1_scores]  
def flip(x):
    return np.concatenate([x[:,5:], x[:,:5]], axis=1)

#this function interweaves 2 vectors so that [0,0,0] and [1,1,1] becomes [0,1,0,1,0,1]
def interweave(a,b):
    c = np.empty((a.shape[0] + b.shape[0],a.shape[1]), dtype=a.dtype)
    c[0::2] = a
    c[1::2] = b
    return c

net = input_data(shape=[None, 10])
net = fully_connected(net, 32, activation='relu')
net = fully_connected(net, 16, activation='relu')
net = fully_connected(net, 1, activation='sigmoid')
net = regression(net, shuffle_batches=True, loss='binary_crossentropy')
model = tflearn.DNN(net)

x = np.load("scores.npy")
x_flipped = flip(x)

#x is sorted such that the winning team always comes first in the input vector, so the labels are all 1
y = np.ones((x.shape[0], 1))
y_flipped = np.zeros((x.shape[0], 1))

x_symmetric = interweave(x, x_flipped)
y_symmetric = interweave(y, y_flipped)

for epoch in range(100):
    model.fit(x_symmetric, y_symmetric, n_epoch=1, shuffle=True, validation_set=None, show_metric=True, batch_size=128)
    acc_reg = model.evaluate(x, y)[0]
    acc_flip = model.evaluate(x_flipped, y_flipped)[0]
    print(f"1 prediction: {acc_reg}      0 prediction: {acc_flip}")
```

And here is the training data: [scores.npy](https://filebin.net/b636ghn7pbno4hsd)
The training data is standardized and sorted so that the winning team comes before the losing team. Thus all labels are 1

Comment: "Despite the test and training data and labels being balanced" Are you saying that test and train have same amount of data?

Comment: This happens to be the case here but what I mean is that the label classes [0,1] both have the exact same number of training samples.

Comment: I'm confused, you are predicting which team is winning based on the sums of team1 and team2?

Comment: or are you trying to predict who WILL win, based on the current state of the sum of the teams?

Comment: The latter. Also there is no summing. I feed the standardized scores into the network, so the input data vector has shape: (-1, 10). This represents a snapshot of the game at a given point in time. Then the network outputs 1 if the team that is in [-1, :5] is winning or it outputs 0 if the team that is in [-1, 5:] is winning